# Shop image dont change

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an issue with the backgroung of shop-image here is the [LINK](https://fron-gsm.com/shop) to shop page, and here is a screenshot
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRQ2U.jpg)

Here is the code that i tryed to change background :

```
div.page-title.page-title-default.title-size-default.color-scheme-light.title-design-centered.title-shop  {
background-image:none;
background-color:#111111;
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to background-image property, try this:

```
div.page-title.page-title-default.title-size-default.color-scheme-light.title-design-centered.title-shop  {
/* important */
   background-image:none !important;
   background-color:#111111;
}
```